# Excel not updating collections when using MongoDB BI Connector via Atlas

Tags: excel, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have been able to connect Excel to Atlas via the MongoDB BI connector. I  loaded a database and collection on Atlas via pymongo, this collection pulled as a data table in excel successfully. Then I deleted the database 'autodb' and collection 'passveh'. I then recreated the database 'autodb' and uploaded two new collections 'nev_by_drive_train' 'pv_bev_by_region' in the same database. But now when refreshing in excel, the old database and collection show instead of the new ones. Any ideas how to get excel to refresh and show the new database and collections?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting a value for `Sample Refresh Interval (Optional)` in your cluster configuration for BI Connector.

The default value is `0` meaning sampling will never repeat after initialization.